# Getwork - can the miner increment timestamp?

Tags: bitcoind, mining-pools, mining-technical-details, getwork, timestamp

When requesting getwork from bitcoind or a pool, the miner is expected to be incrementing the nonce value of the block, but can it also increment the timestamp value, or would such tempering cause a submitted work to be rejected by bitcoind or a given pool?

Comment: It depends on the pool's policy. This is called [NTime rolling](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-is-ntime-rolling-nonce-range-and-what-miners-support-it).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Hmm, I was thinking that's what it should be, although some descriptions for NTime rolling implied that it allows a miner not to discard an unfinished getwork after one second, not that it allows the miner to increment timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the miner can increment the time stamp by a limited amount, but *only* if the pool advertises X-Roll-NTime as a feature. DiabloMiner and CGMiner both support this.

See the [official spec](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork#rollntime) for more information.